# Is there a rule for how to pronounce words such as "dance", "prance", "castle"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels, transatlantic-differences, ae-raising

Is there a grammatical rule for the pronunciation of words such as *dance, castle* and *prance*? I believe the British English pronunciation is "ah", while in American English it is a short "a" sound.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be pedantic, but  it's not grammar. In linguistics, grammar is the set of structural rules that governs the composition of clauses, phrases, and words in any given natural language [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar)]. The way words are pronounced is *phonetics:* the branch of linguistics that comprises the study of the sounds of human speech. [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetics)].

Pronunciation is one aspect of dialect. It's true that Americans and Southern Englishmen pronounce *dance* differently, although both can be represented /dɑːns/ because the /ɑː/ symbol between slashes is a broad transcriptional device. A more accurate transcription of the American *dance* might be [däns] or [dɐns]. Northern English makes the *a* in *dance* much shorter than Southern English and it's more like /dæns/. In the English West Country it's different again: [dɐᵊns].

As for **rules,** well, no: it's custom and practice. The American pronunciation of *mass* is different to the English, but Northern and Southern English are generally almost identical to each other, with a short vowel (some Southerners pronounce it /mɑːs/ but it sounds affected these days). Because pronunciation of vowels in particular is not matched to spelling — think of *bough, cough, dough, tough* as obvious examples — it's difficult to come up with any rules for how to differentiate between [ä] [ɑː] [ɐ] [æ] and [ɐᵊ] in *dance.* And there are some words where rules simply don't apply: one text-to-speech program I used insisted on pronouncing *without* as /woʊ'ʒiːtɑ/! I still don't know if there is any dialect of English which actually does that.

The only way of learning pronunciation truly accurately is immersion and practice.

Comment: Very important that non-UK dwellers understand how different pronunciation can be north and south of the Midlands. It is often that we ourselves forget. Only last week we were in Manchester and my wife, asking in Tesco where she could find a 'bath mat', got flummoxed looks from the assistant.

Comment: How can the American word *dance* be represented as /dɑːns/? The IPA symbol /ɑ/ can be used for [father](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/father), [spa](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/spa), [pot](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pot), and, in some dialects, [caught](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/caught). But we don't pronounce [dance](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dance) with a vowel anywhere close to that.

Comment: @PeterShor I don’t know that I’ve heard a North American say *dance* any other way that /dæns/.  I suppose there may be some nasalization in some speakers, or some *bag–beg* type collisions in others, but I don’t think it really changes that much here. Outside of certain choral performances, I’m pretty sure it is never the /ɑ/ as in *not*: that sounds pretentious as all get out.

Comment: I am from [Wiltshire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiltshire), a county that is undoubtedly part of the [West Country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westcountry) and the dialectical peculiarities of that region are often overlooked. This is a particular sore point as the place name [Bath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bath,_Somerset) is a homonym with **bath** and often used as a gauge of whether or not someone is 'southern'. People actually from **Bath** pronounce **bath** with neither of the commonly accepted variants. And **that** accent is different again to mine.

Answer (score 0):

A linguistic abstraction for comparison of vowel pronunciation in different dialects is called lexical sets, for UK and US English there are [Wells lexical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_UK_and_US_English), of which you need BATH set. Some rules about [trap-bath split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8a%E2%9F%A9#Trap.E2.80.93bath_split) show which words may fall into BATH set, though it is unpredictable. In the table there is a mix of BATH and PALM words, as they are indistinguishable in UK accent alone, so see also [a more correct example list](http://www.yorku.ca/earmstro/courses/phonetics/lexical_sets.pdf) based on Wells' *Accents of English* or the book itself.